# Update data in laravel, when there a data that is primary key

Tags: php, laravel

i want to edit data, and the id is primary key.
but when i submit, the database does not change.

here the code

controller :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
         $karyawan = Karyawan :: find ($id); 
         $jabatan = Jabatan::all();
         return view ('/karyawan.editData', compact(('karyawan'),('jabatan')));
          
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'id' => 'required',
            'nama'=> 'required',
            'umur'=>'required',
            'alamat'=> 'required',
            'nomor'=> 'required'
        ]);
        
        $karyawan =Karyawan::find($id);
        $karyawan->jabatan_id = $request->jabatan;
        $karyawan->nama = $request->nama;
        // $karyawan->id = $request->id;
        $karyawan->umur = $request->umur;
        $karyawan->alamat = $request->alamat;
        $karyawan->nomor = $request->nomor;    
        $karyawan->save();
        
        return redirect ('/karyawan');
    }
```

and the editData :

```
@extends ('layout')
@section ('content')

<h1>Edit Data Karyawan </h1>
 <form action="/karyawan/{{ $karyawan->Id }}" method="post"> 
    {{-- <form action = "/karyawan" method="post"> --}}
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for = "title">ID Jabatan</label>
            <select name="jabatan" class="form-control">
                @foreach ($jabatan as $baris)
                <option value = "{{ $baris->id}}">{{ $baris->nm_jabatan }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <div class = "form-group"> 
                <label for="title"> nama</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama">
            </div>
        <div class = "a"> 
            <label for="title"> ID </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id" value = "{{ old('id') ? old('id'): $karyawan->id }}">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group"> 
            <label for="title"> umur</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="umur">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group"> 
            <label for="title"> alamat</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group"> 
            <label for="title"> nomor</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomor">
        </div>
        <a href="/karyawan"> 
            <button type = "button" class="btn btn-warning">kembali</button>
        </a>
        <button type ="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

how i can update the data? from these code
i expect to get some explanation, and show me how to fix my code. so i can submit the update data on my database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validated_data = $request->validate([
        'name'      => 'required|max:255', (add all the form here)
    ]);

    YourModel::where('id', $id)->update($validated_data);

    return redirect('admin/problem')->with('success', 'Data berhasil diubah');
}
```

Tips* dump all the request with dd($request->all) so you can see all of your input form data